# Web Audio Offline Context and Analyser Node

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Is it possible to use the `Analyser` node in the `offlineAudioContext` to do frequency analysis?

I found out that `ScriptProcessor` 's `onaudioprocess` event still fires in the `offlineAudioContext` and this was the only event source I could use to call `getByteFrequencyData` of the `Analyser` Node. As below:

```
var offline = new offlineAudioContext(1, buffer.length, 44100);
var bufferSource = offline.createBufferSource();
bufferSource.buffer = buffer;

var analyser = offline.createAnalyser();
var scp = offline.createScriptProcessor(256, 0, 1);

bufferSource.connect(analyser);
scp.connect(offline.destination); // this is necessary for the script processor to start

var freqData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
scp.onaudioprocess = function(){
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(freqData);
    console.log(freqData);
   // freqData is always the same.
};

bufferSource.start(0);
offline.startRendering();
```

The problem here is that `freqData` array is always the same and never changes. Seem like as if it is only analysing one section of the buffer.

Am I doing anything wrong here? Or the `Analyser` is not intended to be used in the `offlineContext`.

And here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsanziya/7fouhvfo/4/) with the same code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analyser isn't really intended to be used in the offlineContext; in fact, it was originally named "RealtimeAnalyser".  But even more importantly, right now you won't get consistent functionality from script processors in offline contexts, either.

Comment: Fair enough, although the ability to use the analyser node and scriptprocessor would be great feature for the offline context. @cwilso

Comment: The new worker script nodes should work just fine in offline.

Comment: Is this still the case with the AnalyserNode & OfflineAudioContext? Or is it possible to do frequency analysis of a BufferSource in offline mode?

Comment: Not using an AnalyserNode, no.  You'd be best off grabbing a library to do this directly, like DSP.js.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use the `suspend` and `resume` methods available for an `OfflineAudioContext`.  After suspending, you can use your analyser node to get the desired time and/or frequency domain data.  Since the context is stopped, this works just fine.  If you're going to do this several times, you'll need to schedule a stop for the next time before resuming.

Unfortunately, AFAIK, only Chrome has implemented `suspend` for an `OfflineAudioContext`